# htaccess redirect using not english characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

htaccess works without problem when i`m using english characters.
but when I use not english characters, it cant redirect and shows :

**Not Found
The requested URL**

these are my sample code. I have tasted it different types but nono of them works :

```
Redirect 301 "/مقاله-انواع-دسته-بندی-برج-های-خنک-کننده" /destination
Redirect 301 "/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B9-%D8%AF%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AC-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AE%D9%86%DA%A9-%DA%A9%D9%86%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87" /destination
```

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to redirect?

Comment: this is my url : www.sample.com/مقاله-انواع-دسته-بندی-برج-های-خنک-کننده

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your Apache configuration file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

then restart your Apache server.  After this, you may use your htaccess file which contains redirects with UTF-8 characters, and they should now be recognized.  You should make sure that you save your htaccess file in a format which supports UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^مقاله-انواع-دسته-بندی-برج-های-خنک-کننده/?$ /destination [L,B,R=301]
```